# Как показать нужное изображение в QMessageBox в зависимости от нажатия на определенную кнопку с ответом

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qmessagebox

После нажатия на подсказку  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводится определённая картинка в зависимости от правильного ответа.

Я сделал в функции

```
def clicked_audience(self):
    if audience_image
       ...
```

где `audience_image = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0]`

То есть оно равно правильному ответу под номером **`0`** (первому).
Мне нужно чтобы не писать `if self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][9] or self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][8]: or self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][7]:`

К примеру в списке под этими номерами лежит правильные ответы на букву **`А`** и я хочу сделать покороче `if А`, то он тогда будет очень большой, ну или же если не получится то не судьба.

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import webbrowser
import random 
import time


class WindowGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('windowgroup')

        self.list_questions = [                  
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що мають на увазі кажучи: "пройшов вогонь, воду і мідні труби"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який материк найбільший?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Куди вказує червона стрілка компаса?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який пігмент забарвлює листя в зелений колір?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який препарат марно намагалися отримати середньовічні алхіміки?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як правильно кликати гусака?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Якій кухні належить блюдо "форшмак"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Яку рослину називають «живим світлофором»?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що є туманністю Андромеди?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Назвіть офіційну мову Шрі-Ланки:</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Столицею якої країни є місто Богота?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Які літальні апарати конструював Отто Ліліенталь?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якому столітті в Китаї почали добувати залізо?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якій мові програмування немає засобів роботи з файлами?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У яких тварин офіційно реєструвалися сонячні удари, подібні до людських?</h1>',
        ]

        self.quantity_questions = len(self.list_questions) 

        self.list_buttons = [                                     
            ['А: Навчання', 'В: Самогон', 'С: Стаж', 'D: Досвід'],
            ['А: Північна Америка', 'В: Південна Америка', 'С: Африка', 'D: Євразія'],
            ['А: Північ', 'В: Схід', 'С: Захід', 'D: Південь'],
            ['А: Каротин', 'В: Антоціан', 'С: Хлорофіл', 'D: Танін'],
            ['А: Настоянку мудрості', 'В: Засіб від лупи', 'С: Еліксир життя', 'D: Напій сміливості'],
            ['А: Киць-киць', 'В: Гуль-гуль', 'С: Тега-тега', 'D: Курчат-курчат'],
            ['А: Єврейській', 'В: Грузинській', 'С: Китайській', 'D: Індійській'],
            ['А: Акаліфа', 'В: Медуниця', 'С: Маранта', 'D: Кротон'],
            ['А: Метеорит', 'В: Зірка', "С: Сузір'я", 'D: Галактика'],
            ['А: Урду', 'В: Сінгальский', 'С: Бенгальський', 'D: Брахми'],
            ['А: Чилі', 'В: Перу' ,'С: Аргентина', 'D: Колумбія'],
            ['А: Вертольоти', 'В: Дирижаблі', 'С: Літаки-біплани', 'D: Планери'],
            ['А: 4 вік до н.е', 'В: 2 вік', 'С: 3 вік', 'D: 5 вік до н.е.'],
            ['А: PHP', 'В: Delphi', 'С: C++', 'D: JavaScript'],
            ['А: У собак', 'В: У кішок', 'С: У свиней', 'D: У кроликів']
        ]
        self.list_yes_buttons = [                      
            'D: Досвід',
            'D: Євразія',
            'D: Південь',
            'С: Хлорофіл',
            'С: Еліксир життя',
            'С: Тега-тега',
            'А: Єврейській',
            'В: Медуниця',
            'D: Галактика',
            'В: Сінгальский',
            'D: Колумбія',
            'D: Планери',
            'D: 5 вік до н.е.',
            'D: JavaScript',
            'D: У кроликів'
        ]
        self.current_question = 0 

        self.label = QLabel(self.list_questions[self.current_question])

        self.radioGroupBox = QGroupBox('') 
        self.radioGroup = QButtonGroup() 

        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton('А: Навчання')
        self.rbtn_1.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_2 = QPushButton('В: Самогон')
        self.rbtn_2.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_3 = QPushButton('С: Стаж')
        self.rbtn_3.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_4 = QPushButton('D: Досвід')
        self.rbtn_4.setFixedSize(740, 49) 

        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_1)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_2)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_3)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_4)

        self.hint_5050 = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_5050.setIcon(QIcon('5050_normal.png'))
        self.hint_5050.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_5050.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_audience = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_audience.setIcon(QIcon('audience_normal.png'))
        self.hint_audience.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_audience.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_expert = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_expert.setIcon(QIcon('expert_normal.png'))
        self.hint_expert.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_expert.setFixedSize(120, 100)      

        self.hint_switch = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_switch.setIcon(QIcon('switch_2_normal.png'))
        self.hint_switch.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_switch.setFixedSize(120, 100)         

        layout_ans1 = QHBoxLayout()  
        layout_ans2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans3 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_1) 
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_2)
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_3) 
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_4)

        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans2)
        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans3) 

        self.radioGroupBox.setLayout(layout_ans1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioGroupBox)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                  
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName('centralWidget')          
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  

        self.num = 3

        self.question = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">Правила гри')

        self.rules = QLabel('''Гра "Хто хоче стати мільйонером?" 
\
Ви повинні правильно відповісти на низку питань \
з кількома варіантами відповідей, щоб заробити 3.000.000 грн. \
Всього 15 питань, кожне питання коштує певної суми грошей, \
учасники не мають жодних тимчасових обмежень для надання \
відповіді. Учасник також отримуює 4 види підказок, щоб допомогти собі, \
якщо вони застрягли на конкретному питанні.  
\
Більше ознайомитися з правилами можна, натиснувши на кнопку. 
\
Хай щастить!''')
        self.rules.setStyleSheet("""
        font: bold;
        color: rgb(185, 255, 0);
    """)
        self.rules.setFixedSize(1010,450)
        self.rules.setObjectName('rules')
        self.rules.setWordWrap(True)    

        self.button_rules = QPushButton('Правила')
        self.button_rules.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://ru.wwbm.com/rules'))
        self.button_rules.setFixedSize(300,50)


        self.button_start = QPushButton('Почати', clicked=self._start)  
        self.button_start.setFixedSize(300,50)
        
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.lineH1 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH2 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineH1.addWidget(self.question, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        lineH2.addWidget(self.rules)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_rules, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_start, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.lineH1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.rules, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(lineH3)


        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)

        self.windowGroup = WindowGroup()

        self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.list_rbtn = [
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4,
        ] 
        self.correct_answer = '<h1 style="color: #4E9F3D;">Це вірна відповідь!</h1>'
        self.wrong_answer = '<h1 style="color: #DA0037;">Це НЕ вірна відповідь!</h1>'

        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.clicked.connect(self.clicked_5050)
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.clicked.connect(self.clicked_audience)

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
        sender = self.sender()  
        self.sender_click = sender
        if sender.text() in self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.correct_answer}' 
            )                 
        else:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.wrong_answer}' 
            )         
            self.windowGroup.current_question = self.windowGroup.quantity_questions
            self.num = 3    
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.third)  

    def set_stylesheet(self):  
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel, QPushButton {
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
            #rules { 
                background-color: #ccffbd;
            }
            #windowgroup > QLabel { 
                font-size: 11pt;
            }
            #windowgroup > QGroupBox { 
                background-color: #a44500;
                font-size: 20pt;
                width: 620px; height: 49px;
            }
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #D98C00;
                font-size: 34px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0082fc;
                border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
            }
            #centralWidget {
                background-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            #window_audience {
                backround-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            """) 
        
    def update_timer(self):        
        self.question.setText(f'<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">{self.num}</h1>')
        if self.num == 0:
            self.timer.stop()
            
            self.set_stylesheet()                 

            self.question.setPixmap(QPixmap("million.png"))
            self.num = 3
            self.rules.hide()
            self.button_start.hide()
            self.button_rules.hide()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.windowGroup, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

            self.lineH1.insertStretch(0)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(1, self.windowGroup.hint_5050)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(2)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(3, self.windowGroup.hint_audience)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(4)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_expert)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_switch)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)

            return            
        self.num -= 1        

    def _start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)     

    def third(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(True)  
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(True)      
        
        if self.windowGroup.current_question + 1 < self.windowGroup.quantity_questions:

            self.windowGroup.current_question += 1
            
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])
            
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][2])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][1])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][3])                
            
            self.set_stylesheet()            
        else:
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                '<h1 style="color: #FFDD93;">Гру закінчено, дякуємо за участь!</h1>'
            )             
            self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
            self.sender_click.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: #D98C00; width: 780px; height: 49px;")
            self.set_stylesheet() 
            
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:    
            rbtn.setEnabled(True)
            rbtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    background-color: #D98C00; 
                    width: 620px; height: 49px;
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    background-color: #0082fc;
                    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
                }
            """)
            
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   

    def clicked_5050(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)
        
        current_question = self.windowGroup.current_question
        list_yes_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[current_question]
        list_5050 = [list_yes_buttons,]
        
        not_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_buttons[current_question]
        not_buttons.remove(list_yes_buttons)
        not_buttons = random.choices(not_buttons)

        list_5050.append(not_buttons[0])
        
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:
            if rbtn.text() in list_5050:
                pass
            else:
                rbtn.setEnabled(False)

        
    def clicked_audience(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.setEnabled(False)

        window_audience = QMessageBox(self)
        window_audience.setWindowIcon(QIcon("audience_normal.png"))
        window_audience.setWindowTitle('Допомога зали') 
        audience_image = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0] 

        
        if audience_image:
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_D.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        elif self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][9]:
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_A.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        window_audience.exec_()  

        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            font-size: 20pt;
        }
        QPushButton { 
            font-size: 20pt;
            background-color: #ff8000;
        }
        #centralWidget {
            background-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
        #centeralMessage {
            backround-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
    """)
    w = MainWindow()          
    w.setWindowTitle('Million')  
    w.resize(1700, 770)
    w.move(125, 110)
    w.show()                           
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем уверен, что правильно понял что вы хотите сделать.

**ВНИМАНИЕ**! Списки `self.list_buttons` и `self.list_yes_buttons`, а также название кнопок `self.rbtn_1`, `self.rbtn_2`, `self.rbtn_3`, `self.rbtn_4` - возьмите из моего примера и исправьте во всех своих копиях. Первая литера везде должна быть на английском языке.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import webbrowser
import random 
import time


class WindowGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('windowgroup')

        self.list_questions = [                  
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що мають на увазі кажучи: "пройшов вогонь, воду і мідні труби"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який материк найбільший?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Куди вказує червона стрілка компаса?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який пігмент забарвлює листя в зелений колір?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Який препарат марно намагалися отримати середньовічні алхіміки?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Як правильно кликати гусака?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Якій кухні належить блюдо "форшмак"?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Яку рослину називають «живим світлофором»?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Що є туманністю Андромеди?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Назвіть офіційну мову Шрі-Ланки:</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Столицею якої країни є місто Богота?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">Які літальні апарати конструював Отто Ліліенталь?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якому столітті в Китаї почали добувати залізо?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У якій мові програмування немає засобів роботи з файлами?</h1>',
            '<h1 style="color: rgb(185, 255, 0);">У яких тварин офіційно реєструвалися сонячні удари, подібні до людських?</h1>',
        ]

        self.quantity_questions = len(self.list_questions) 

        self.list_buttons = [ 
# +++         V              V             V          V <---- это английские буевы   !!!        
            ['A: Навчання', 'B: Самогон', 'C: Стаж', 'D: Досвід'],
            ['A: Північна Америка', 'B: Південна Америка', 'C: Африка', 'D: Євразія'],
            ['A: Північ', 'B: Схід', 'C: Захід', 'D: Південь'],
            ['A: Каротин', 'B: Антоціан', 'C: Хлорофіл', 'D: Танін'],
            ['A: Настоянку мудрості', 'B: Засіб від лупи', 'C: Еліксир життя', 'D: Напій сміливості'],
            ['A: Киць-киць', 'B: Гуль-гуль', 'C: Тега-тега', 'D: Курчат-курчат'],
            ['A: Єврейській', 'B: Грузинській', 'C: Китайській', 'D: Індійській'],
            ['A: Акаліфа', 'B: Медуниця', 'C: Маранта', 'D: Кротон'],
            ['A: Метеорит', 'B: Зірка', "C: Сузір'я", 'D: Галактика'],
            ['A: Урду', 'B: Сінгальский', 'C: Бенгальський', 'D: Брахми'],
            ['A: Чилі', 'B: Перу' ,'C: Аргентина', 'D: Колумбія'],
            ['A: Вертольоти', 'B: Дирижаблі', 'C: Літаки-біплани', 'D: Планери'],
            ['A: 4 вік до н.е', 'B: 2 вік', 'C: 3 вік', 'D: 5 вік до н.е.'],
            ['A: PHP', 'B: Delphi', 'C: C++', 'D: JavaScript'],
            ['A: У собак', 'B: У кішок', 'C: У свиней', 'D: У кроликів']
        ]
        self.list_yes_buttons = [ 
# +++        V                              <---- это английские буевы   !!!        
            'D: Досвід',
            'D: Євразія',
            'D: Південь',
# +++        V                              <---- это английские буевы   !!!  
            'C: Хлорофіл',
            'C: Еліксир життя',
            'C: Тега-тега',
# +++        V                              <---- это английские буевы   !!!  
            'A: Єврейській',
# +++        V                              <---- это английские буевы   !!!  
            'B: Медуниця',
            'D: Галактика',
# +++        V                              <---- это английские буевы   !!!  
            'B: Сінгальский',
            'D: Колумбія',
            'D: Планери',
            'D: 5 вік до н.е.',
            'D: JavaScript',
            'D: У кроликів'
        ]
        self.current_question = 0 

        self.label = QLabel(self.list_questions[self.current_question])

        self.radioGroupBox = QGroupBox('') 
        self.radioGroup = QButtonGroup() 

# +++                              V  <---- это английские буевы   !!!
        self.rbtn_1 = QPushButton('A: Навчання')
        self.rbtn_1.setFixedSize(740, 49)
# +++                              V  <---- это английские буевы   !!!
        self.rbtn_2 = QPushButton('B: Самогон')
        self.rbtn_2.setFixedSize(740, 49)
# +++                              V  <---- это английские буевы   !!!
        self.rbtn_3 = QPushButton('C: Стаж')
        self.rbtn_3.setFixedSize(740, 49)
        self.rbtn_4 = QPushButton('D: Досвід')
        self.rbtn_4.setFixedSize(740, 49) 

        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_1)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_2)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_3)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_4)

        self.hint_5050 = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_5050.setIcon(QIcon('5050_normal.png'))
        self.hint_5050.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_5050.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_audience = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_audience.setIcon(QIcon('audience_normal.png'))
        self.hint_audience.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_audience.setFixedSize(120, 100)

        self.hint_expert = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_expert.setIcon(QIcon('expert_normal.png'))
        self.hint_expert.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_expert.setFixedSize(120, 100)      

        self.hint_switch = QPushButton(self)
        self.hint_switch.setIcon(QIcon('switch_2_normal.png'))
        self.hint_switch.setIconSize(QSize(105, 90))
        self.hint_switch.setFixedSize(120, 100)         

        layout_ans1 = QHBoxLayout()  
        layout_ans2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans3 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_1) 
        layout_ans2.addWidget(self.rbtn_2)
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_3) 
        layout_ans3.addWidget(self.rbtn_4)

        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans2)
        layout_ans1.addLayout(layout_ans3) 

        self.radioGroupBox.setLayout(layout_ans1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioGroupBox)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                                  
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName('centralWidget')          
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  

        self.num = 3

        self.question = QLabel('<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">Правила гри')

        self.rules = QLabel('''Гра "Хто хоче стати мільйонером?" 
\
Ви повинні правильно відповісти на низку питань \
з кількома варіантами відповідей, щоб заробити 3.000.000 грн. \
Всього 15 питань, кожне питання коштує певної суми грошей, \
учасники не мають жодних тимчасових обмежень для надання \
відповіді. Учасник також отримуює 4 види підказок, щоб допомогти собі, \
якщо вони застрягли на конкретному питанні.  
\
Більше ознайомитися з правилами можна, натиснувши на кнопку. 
\
Хай щастить!''')
        self.rules.setStyleSheet("""
        font: bold;
        color: rgb(185, 255, 0);
    """)
        self.rules.setFixedSize(1010,450)
        self.rules.setObjectName('rules')
        self.rules.setWordWrap(True)    

        self.button_rules = QPushButton('Правила')
        self.button_rules.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://ru.wwbm.com/rules'))
        self.button_rules.setFixedSize(300,50)


        self.button_start = QPushButton('Почати', clicked=self._start)  
        self.button_start.setFixedSize(300,50)
        
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.lineH1 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH2 = QHBoxLayout()
        lineH3 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lineH1.addWidget(self.question, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        lineH2.addWidget(self.rules)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_rules, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lineH3.addWidget(self.button_start, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.lineH1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.rules, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.layout.addLayout(lineH3)
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_timer)

        self.windowGroup = WindowGroup()

        self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.list_rbtn = [
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3,
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4,
        ] 
        self.correct_answer = '<h1 style="color: #4E9F3D;">Це вірна відповідь!</h1>'
        self.wrong_answer = '<h1 style="color: #DA0037;">Це НЕ вірна відповідь!</h1>'

        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.clicked.connect(self.clicked_5050)
# !!!
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.clicked.connect(self.clicked_audience)

# +++   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.hint_audience = False                                       # +++

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
        sender = self.sender()  
        self.sender_click = sender
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        if self.hint_audience:
            #print(f'{sender.text()} -- {sender.text()[0]}') #
            self.audience_messageBox(sender.text()[0])
            self.windowGroup.hint_audience.setEnabled(True)
            self.hint_audience = False
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        if sender.text() in self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;")
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.correct_answer}' 
            )                 
        else:
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                f'{self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question]} \
                {self.wrong_answer}' 
            )         
            self.windowGroup.current_question = self.windowGroup.quantity_questions
            self.num = 3    
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.third)  

    def set_stylesheet(self):  
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel, QPushButton {
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
            #rules { 
                background-color: #ccffbd;
            }
            #windowgroup > QLabel { 
                font-size: 11pt;
            }
            #windowgroup > QGroupBox { 
                background-color: #a44500;
                font-size: 20pt;
                width: 620px; height: 49px;
            }
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #D98C00;
                font-size: 34px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0082fc;
                border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
            }
            #centralWidget {
                background-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            #window_audience {
                backround-image: url(first.jpg);
            }
            """) 
        
    def update_timer(self):        
        self.question.setText(f'<h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">{self.num}</h1>')
        if self.num == 0:
            self.timer.stop()
            
            self.set_stylesheet()                 

            self.question.setPixmap(QPixmap("million.png"))
            self.num = 3
            self.rules.hide()
            self.button_start.hide()
            self.button_rules.hide()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.windowGroup, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

            self.lineH1.insertStretch(0)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(1, self.windowGroup.hint_5050)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(2)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(3, self.windowGroup.hint_audience)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(4)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_expert)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)
            self.lineH1.insertWidget(-1, self.windowGroup.hint_switch)
            self.lineH1.insertStretch(-1)

            return            
        self.num -= 1        

    def _start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)     

    def third(self):
        self.windowGroup.setEnabled(True)  
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(True)      
        
        if self.windowGroup.current_question + 1 < self.windowGroup.quantity_questions:

            self.windowGroup.current_question += 1
            
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_questions[self.windowGroup.current_question])
            
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_1.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][0])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_2.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][2])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_3.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][1])
            self.windowGroup.rbtn_4.setText(
                self.windowGroup.list_buttons[self.windowGroup.current_question][3])                
            
            self.set_stylesheet()            
        else:
            self.windowGroup.label.setText(
                '<h1 style="color: #FFDD93;">Гру закінчено, дякуємо за участь!</h1>'
            )             
            self.windowGroup.setEnabled(False)
            self.sender_click.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: #D98C00; width: 780px; height: 49px;")
            self.set_stylesheet() 
            
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:    
            rbtn.setEnabled(True)
            rbtn.setStyleSheet("""
                QPushButton {
                    background-color: #D98C00; 
                    width: 620px; height: 49px;
                }
                QPushButton:hover {
                    background-color: #0082fc;
                    border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
                }
            """)
            
        self.windowGroup.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)   

    def clicked_5050(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_5050.setEnabled(False)
        
        current_question = self.windowGroup.current_question
        list_yes_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_yes_buttons[current_question]
        list_5050 = [list_yes_buttons,]
        
        not_buttons = self.windowGroup.list_buttons[current_question]
        not_buttons.remove(list_yes_buttons)
        not_buttons = random.choices(not_buttons)

        list_5050.append(not_buttons[0])
        
        for rbtn in self.list_rbtn:
            if rbtn.text() in list_5050:
                pass
            else:
                rbtn.setEnabled(False)

# !!! 
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
    def clicked_audience(self):
        self.windowGroup.hint_audience.setEnabled(False)
        self.hint_audience = True
        
    def audience_messageBox(self, letter):        
        window_audience = QMessageBox(self)
        window_audience.setWindowIcon(QIcon("audience_normal.png"))
        window_audience.setWindowTitle('Допомога зали') 

        if letter == 'D':
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_D.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        elif letter == 'A':
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_A.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        elif letter == 'B':
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_B.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
        elif letter == 'C':
            window_audience.setIconPixmap(
                QPixmap("audience_C.png").scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )
            
        window_audience.exec_()  
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel {
            font-size: 20pt;
        }
        QPushButton { 
            font-size: 20pt;
            background-color: #ff8000;
        }
        #centralWidget {
            background-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
        #centeralMessage {
            backround-image: url(first.jpg);
        }
    """)
    w = MainWindow()          
    w.setWindowTitle('Million')  
    w.resize(1700, 770)
    w.move(125, 110)
    w.show()                           
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного не так. Нужно что бы высвечивалась картинка  с голосованием  перед нажатием на кнопку.

Comment: @NikitaKhistov вывод картинки можно вставить куда угодно. Сформулируйте четко критерий вывода картинки до нажатия на кнопку ответа и если сами не разберетесь с местом установки вызова window_audience.exec_() - зададите новый вопрос. Еще раз, вы должны четко и однозначно сформулировать критерии выбора нужного изображения.